# RViz quietly ignores if .rviz file given with -d option doesn't exist?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

e.g. in Hydro,

```
$ rosrun rviz rviz -d $(rospack find urdf_tutorial)/urdf.rviz
$ rosrun rviz rviz -d $(rospack find urdf_tutorial)/urdf_noexist.rviz
```

With first line loads RobotModel pane for instance. With second line no error output printed, `RViz` looks like starts with default config.

ros-hydro-rviz 1.10.9-0raring-20131124-0032-+0000

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107516/rviz-quietly-ignores-if-.rviz-file-given-with--d-option-doesn%27t-exist?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's the same behavior I've seen - rviz starts but doesn't create that file until you save the config. I assumed this behavior was intended.

---

Originally posted by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) with karma: 435 on 2013-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0